# SQL Server Restore Database Time Difference on Different Servers

Tags: sql-server

I have two servers:

Server A
- Windows 2019 Standard server with 64 GB of installed RAM.
- D Drive with 1.26 TB memory

Server B
- Windows 2022 Standard server with 200 GB of installed RAM.
- D Drive with 2.5 TB memory

As a part of an agent job, I use azcopy to copy a .bak file (~90gb) from Server C to
both Servers A and B. To copy to either server takes the same amount of time.
To restore the backup on Server A takes roughly 40 minutes. On Server B
the restore takes over 60 minutes consistently. The rest of the ETL on Server A is about 40 minutes faster than B, they are running the same job.

What might cause the difference in restore speed?

Comment: Hardware? Are the drives the same model? Formatted the same (NTFS, block size?) Drivers the same? Both fully up to date?

Comment: Hardware the same. Drives same model. Formatted the same. Driver is slightly newer version on server B. @Charlieface

Comment: I have very limited DBA experience, I am a developer who is just trying to understand what could cause this difference. @Charlieface

Answer (score -3):

This article might explain the performance difference.
https://www.diskpart.com/server-2022/windows-server-2022-very-slow-0725.html

Server 2022 has higher hardware requirements to realize the higher performance; if your Windows Server has poor performance, it’s can be related to the hardware and something else.